# Weka displaying weird results for classification - question marks"?"

Tags: weka, baseline

I am trying to use the ZeroR algorithm in Weka in order to make baseline performance for my classification problem. However, Weka is displaying weird results for precision and F-measure, it is showing a question mark '?' instead of any number. Anyone knows how can I fix this ?

```
=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

ZeroR predicts class value: label 1

Time taken to build model: 0 seconds

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         431               53.607  %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       373               46.393  %
Kappa statistic                          0     
Mean absolute error                      0.4974
Root mean squared error                  0.4987
Relative absolute error                100      %
Root relative squared error            100      %
Total Number of Instances              804     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.000    0.000    ?          0.000    ?          ?        0.488     0.457     label 0
                 1.000    1.000    0.536      1.000    0.698      ?        0.488     0.530     label 1
Weighted Avg.    0.536    0.536    ?          0.536    ?          ?        0.488     0.496     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   <-- classified as
   0 373 |   a = label 0
   0 431 |   b = label 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wrong.  Note that you have no cases classified as "a", so the precision (etc.) are indeterminable for "a".  Evidently Weka propagates incalculatable values (like Excel does), so the overall precision isn't calculated, either.

Your real problem here is that you  have a model that is classifying everything as "b", which is unlikely to be useful.  But that's ZeroR, so that's just your starting point.

Comment: thanks @zbicyclist for your feedback. Yes I understand the fact that precision is indeterminable for "a" and Weka propagated this to the overall precision, but if we want to rely on the ZeroR output for some reason (reporting results), can we consider the overall precision to be that of 'b' ??

Comment: Yes. Precision is defined this way: Of those cases we predict as X, how many are X? Or, True Positive / (True Positive + False Positive).  So, in this case, that's 431 / (431 + 373) = .536.